# Query Syntax Error in where clause

Tags: java, mysql

I got this error for this query,i know i should use prepared statement to prevent slq injection,but i want to resolve this error.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
Unknown column 's.id' in 'where clause'




ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from shop s,product p where 
                                s.quantity<='"
                                + Quantity
                                + "' and p.model ='"
                                + Model
                                + "' and p.productType='"
                                + Product + "' and s.id=p.id");
```

Comment: Well, does your shop table have a column named 'id'?

Comment: Check the id field name in the shop table.

Comment: yes, my shop table is so composed (id,quantity)

Comment: Show us the DDL of that table.

Comment: INSERT INTO `itshop`.`shop` (`id`, `quantity`) VALUES ('3', '4'); i create a new row for example.

Comment: By the way, please don't construct your queries this way, use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Comment: I think you have two different tables 'shop' in different schemas. One of them is in 'itshop' schema and it contains id, other not.

Comment: yes,just resolved,was that you said @Divers

Comment: Mark then my answer as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two different tables 'shop' in different schemas. One of them is in 'itshop' schema and it contains id, other not.